What is this transpiled code in my react application?
In my React application, I'm using the lodash function set like this:
set(objectToSet, fieldInObjectToSet, valueToSet);

When I look at the transpiled code, I see that this line gets converted to this:
(0,lodash__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__.set)(objectToSet, fieldInObjectToSet, valueToSet);

What is this part: (0,lodash__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__.set)?
It looks like something that references the set function, but what is the leading 0? This also looks like an argument list to a nameless function. Is that what this is?
Thanks!

TL;DR: (0, _.set)(arg) is equivalent to const { set } = _; set(arg);. The only different is the this context in the function call. The transplier using this convention is to make sure the set function call behaves the same without ES6 modules.

@Hao Wu... I see. But what does the 0 do in (0, _.set). I read here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_operator, that the comma operator in this case is evaluating everything from left to right and returns the last (right) item (so the _.set). But why? What is the point of having a comma separated list starting with 0 if the 0 does nothing?

It might be too long to explain in comments, I've added an answer and see if anything else needs to be clarified.

For patterns like this are called indirect function call:
(0, _.set)(...)

The point of this pattern is to return the set function from _ and call it but without the calling context _, with comma operator. The 0 is arbitrary and irrelevant, similar to 0 in void 0, it can literally be anything.
The reason the transpiler doing this is because you called it like
import { set } from 'lodash';  // or similar import
set(...);

but not
import _ from 'lodash'; 
_.set(...)

The difference here is trivial, or none at all. But the transplier is doing this to make sure it's always the same behavior without ES6 Modules.
To demonstrate this discrepancy better, here's a minimal example:


window.name = 'window';

const foo = {
  name: 'foo',
  greeting() {
    console.log(`Hello, I'm ${this.name}!`);
  }
};

// this function is called with calling context of `foo`
foo.greeting();       // > hello, I'm foo

// this function is called with calling context of the current scope, which is `window`
(0, foo.greeting)();  // > hello, I'm window

// which is essentially equivolent to
const { greeting } = foo;
greeting();           // > hello, I'm window




Ah, thanks for the detailed explanation, Hao Wu, it makes sense. So the key take away, if I understand it, is that the comma operator is essential here as it invokes the function that returns the set function (or whatever function is at the end of the list) to a scope outside its original context. So (_.set)(args) wouldn't work because there is no comma operator, and would be equivalent to _.set(args). Is that correct?

Yes, that is correct. (_.set)(args) has no operator nor function involved so the parenthesis does nothing. But together with comma operator like (0, _.set)(args), it purposely dropped the calling context of _.
